# Lineno for 2 column

Tags: two-column, line-numbering

How to add line number to a 2 column document where the line number must appear on the left for the left column and on the right for the right column. The lineno package does not seem to provide this option.

Comment: This is one of the things that's _HARD_ - if not impossible - in LaTeX, while it probably _just works_ in ConTeXt.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the `switch` option for the `lineno` package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %Creates example text
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The line numbers appear on the right of the left column in this answer.

Comment: For numbering of lines on a per-column basis, add the `columnwise` option to [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno).

Comment: @Sony --- Not so on my machine. Make sure you compile twice so that the warning about line number reference goes away.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. Neither did adding the 'columnwise' option as per @Werner

Comment: @DKS --- What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @IanThompson MikTeX. All latest.

Comment: @DKS --- I have no explanation for this. Page 4 of the [lineno package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lineno) says that the `switch` option has this effect. It worked when I posted the answer and it works on my machine now (TeXLive 2014). Perhaps you could ask a new question about the issue, including the `.log` file generated by the example.

Comment: @IanThompson `switch` changes things pagewise, not columnwise. Submitted my Marked Up Manuscript w/o this nice thing though. Will see if I need it again in future.

Comment: @DVK --- you are right; that's the documented behaviour. Perhaps columnwise changes are an undocumented feature that works with some documents but not others. Does my example work on your machine?

Comment: `switch`: Sporadically does the right thing but I can't explain why. Mulitple recompiles needed to achieve the desired result? 
`columnwise`: Line numbers always to the left of the column, line numbers for right column overlap the text of the left column; Line numbers restart at 1 on the right column. Not good. 
`columnwise,switch`: both left and right columns start numbering at line 1 on each page. Not good.

Answer (score 15):

Simply add `[columnwise]` in the options of the package:

```
\usepackage[switch,columnwise]{lineno}
```

Comment: When I use use these options, the counter is reset at every column. However, I am not using one of the default LaTeX classes.

Comment: It is very fruitful for me thaaaaaaaaaaaaaannx 2019

Answer (score 8):

The following is a partial solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-1]
\columnbreak
\rightlinenumbers
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) with the `switch` option, you need to compile at least twice. Your solution works in a different context just as well.

Comment: Does someone know how to make it work with the IEEEtran class?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I've just developed a fortunate hack, or if this is how the package is supposed to be used, but I also had the issue that Ian Thompson's answer did not produce running numbering but columnwise numbering.

I got outer-margin two-column running numbering with the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %Creates example text
\begin{document}
\runningpagewiselinenumbers
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Note that this needs to be compiled twice for the line numbering to be displayed correctly:

```
pdflatex docname.tex
pdflatex docname.tex
```