# Texify: Do you ever need to run it more than once?

Tags: miktex, texify

I've recently discovered MiKTeX's `texify` tool, which appears to run LaTeX/BibTeX repeatedly until the output has stabilised. Is it safe to rely completely on this tool, or are there circumstances where one needs to run it more than once?

Edit: Is there a list of circumstances under which it is safe/unsafe to use `texify`?

(If not, perhaps a 'community wiki' is appropriate here, although I don't really understand what it is?)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/what-are-the-situations-where-you-have-to-compile-a-document-more-than-once

Comment: Another case: if one item in your bibliography cross-refers to another item in your bibliography, you need to run texify twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the code and the packages. For example `pgf` does not generate a rerun warning, if `remember picture` is used, whereas `zref-savepos` uses LaTeX's internal reference system that generates a warning, if the label has changed.

There is package `rerunfilecheck`, that tracks auxiliary files based on MD5 checksums and print rerun warnings, if the contents of the auxiliary files has changed.

But of course, there are documents that never stabilize (the documentation of `varioref` mentions a case). Also the opposite is also true, there are documents with unnecessary rerun warnings.

Comment: Is there any easy way to tell whether something in a particular document is going to be safe to texify?

Comment: @Mohan: You should clarify your question by adding this, but I do not know any such document.

Answer (score 2):

I use `texify` regularly. I’ve changed the latex calls in my TeX editor, and it works fine. Note, that the command line options have to be changed slightly:

```
pdflatex --interaction=batchmode => texify --pdf --batch
pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode => texify --pdf --tex-option="--interaction=nonstopmode"
pdflatex --synctex=1 => texify --pdf --tex-option="--synctex=1"
pdflatex --enable-write18 => texify --pdf --tex-option="--enable-write18"
```

But it does not work together with `biblatex` and especially `biber`, at least the last time I needed it. *And this is a point, where `arara` or `latexmk` get into serious consideration.*

I’ve never looked into it, but the source code should reveal, how `texify` works, see here: http://miktex.org/sources

Comment: 'it works fine': like you I know (empirically) that it's quite reliable; what I'm worried about is the cases where it fails. biblatex/biber are useful to know about.

Comment: Heiko wrote about `pgf`, what is used by `tikz`. I’ve forgotten this, but I observed exactly, what he says regarding “remember picture”.