# Using biber with texify

Tags: biber, texify

I am unable to compile a document using texify and biber. The author of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78060/100410 mentioned there are issues in doing so. **Does anybody know why**? I am aware of `arara` and `latexmk` as alternatives, and have had success with `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex`. Also note, I have an environment variable `BIBTEX` which is set to the full path of my biber executable. MWE and log, below, if it helps.

---

### MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books \autocite{Labov1972,Chomsky1957}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.3.9)  15 MAR 2016 12:09
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/VonmolAL/Documents/mwe.tex
(C:/Users/VonmolAL/Documents/mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.

LaTeX Warning: File `mwe.bib' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2015/12/22 v3.2 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)


Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
(biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
(biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex2.sty
Package: biblatex2 2015/12/22 v3.2 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/A
B)

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count87
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count89

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count90
\c@listtotal=\count91
\c@listcount=\count92
\c@liststart=\count93
\c@liststop=\count94
\c@citecount=\count95
\c@citetotal=\count96
\c@multicitecount=\count97
\c@multicitetotal=\count98
\c@instcount=\count99
\c@maxnames=\count100
\c@minnames=\count101
\c@maxitems=\count102
\c@minitems=\count103
\c@citecounter=\count104
\c@savedcitecounter=\count105
\c@uniquelist=\count106
\c@uniquename=\count107
\c@refsection=\count108
\c@refsegment=\count109
\c@maxextratitle=\count110
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count111
\c@maxextrayear=\count112
\c@maxextraalpha=\count113
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count114
\c@highnamepenalty=\count115
\c@lownamepenalty=\count116
\c@maxparens=\count117
\c@parenlevel=\count118
\blx@tempcnta=\count119
\blx@tempcntb=\count120
\blx@tempcntc=\count121
\blx@maxsection=\count122
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count123
\blx@notetype=\count124
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count125
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count126
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count127
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\biblabelsep=\skip45
\bibitemsep=\skip46
\bibnamesep=\skip47
\bibinitsep=\skip48
\bibparsep=\skip49
\bibhang=\skip50
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\c@mincomprange=\count128
\c@maxcomprange=\count129
\c@mincompwidth=\count130
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count131
\c@savedafterword=\count132
\c@annotator=\count133
\c@savedannotator=\count134
\c@author=\count135
\c@savedauthor=\count136
\c@bookauthor=\count137
\c@savedbookauthor=\count138
\c@commentator=\count139
\c@savedcommentator=\count140
\c@editor=\count141
\c@savededitor=\count142
\c@editora=\count143
\c@savededitora=\count144
\c@editorb=\count145
\c@savededitorb=\count146
\c@editorc=\count147
\c@savededitorc=\count148
\c@foreword=\count149
\c@savedforeword=\count150
\c@holder=\count151
\c@savedholder=\count152
\c@introduction=\count153
\c@savedintroduction=\count154
\c@namea=\count155
\c@savednamea=\count156
\c@nameb=\count157
\c@savednameb=\count158
\c@namec=\count159
\c@savednamec=\count160
\c@translator=\count161
\c@savedtranslator=\count162
\c@shortauthor=\count163
\c@savedshortauthor=\count164
\c@shorteditor=\count165
\c@savedshorteditor=\count166
\c@labelname=\count167
\c@savedlabelname=\count168
\c@institution=\count169
\c@savedinstitution=\count170
\c@lista=\count171
\c@savedlista=\count172
\c@listb=\count173
\c@savedlistb=\count174
\c@listc=\count175
\c@savedlistc=\count176
\c@listd=\count177
\c@savedlistd=\count178
\c@liste=\count179
\c@savedliste=\count180
\c@listf=\count181
\c@savedlistf=\count182
\c@location=\count183
\c@savedlocation=\count184
\c@organization=\count185
\c@savedorganization=\count186
\c@origlocation=\count187
\c@savedoriglocation=\count188
\c@origpublisher=\count189
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count190
\c@publisher=\count191
\c@savedpublisher=\count192
\c@language=\count193
\c@savedlanguage=\count194
\c@pageref=\count195
\c@savedpageref=\count196
\shorthandwidth=\skip51
\shortjournalwidth=\skip52
\shortserieswidth=\skip53
\shorttitlewidth=\skip54
\shortauthorwidth=\skip55
\shorteditorwidth=\skip56
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
 (C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 
\c@textcitecount=\count197
\c@textcitetotal=\count198
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count199
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count200
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count201
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count202
\c@smartand=\count203
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\authoryear
.bbx
File: authoryear.bbx 2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.b
bx
File: standard.bbx 2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count204
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count205
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.cbx' found.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\authoryear
.cbx
File: authoryear.cbx 2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(C:\Users\VonmolAL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lb
x
File: english.lbx 2015/12/22 v3.2 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
\@quotelevel=\count206
\@quotereset=\count207
 (C:\Users\VonmolAL\Documents\mwe.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'mwe.bbl' not found.

No file mwe.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 21.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 21.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Labov1972' on page 1 undefined on input line 22.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Chomsky1957' on page 1 undefined on input line 22.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 23.


Overfull \hbox (8.20482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--24
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Some fa-mous lin-guists wrote a cou-ple of books ([]; []). 
 []

[1

{C:/Users/VonmolAL/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\VonmolAL\Documents\mwe.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                mwe
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'mwe.run.xml'.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6025 strings out of 493921
 105642 string characters out of 3147274
 509740 words of memory out of 3000000
 9316 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3948 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,32p,850b,1012s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 28354 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```