# Sweave function in r fails with Error (option: results seems causing the issue)

Tags: sweave

I got the below function from Prof's website: http://diskworld.wharton.upenn.edu/~foster/teaching/471/sweave-intro.pdf

The said function is meant for converting sweave (.Rnw) into PDF.

But when i run it on my machine, I get this error:

```
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) :
```

'arg' should be one of "verbatim", "tex", "hide"

Function:

```
Sweatex  <- function(filename,extension='Rnw',
     command='pdflatex',silent=FALSE,preview=FALSE) {
  if (command=='latex') command='simpdftex latex --maxpfb'
  extension<-paste('.',extension,sep='')
  path=options('latexcmd')[[1]]
  path=substr(path,start=1,stop=nchar(path)-5)
  Sweave(paste(filename,extension,sep=''))

  system(paste(path,command,' ',filename,sep=''),intern=silent)

  if (preview)
  {
    system(paste(options('pdfviewer')[[1]],' ',filename,'.pdf',sep=''))
  }
}
```

Could anyone throw some lights? Thanks, in advance.

Regards,
Tharma

Comment: Perhaps the right place to ask this is in [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). But you might want to try Rstudio for your Sweave and knitr files. But even without Rstudio, you can compile your .Rnw file into pdf by running `Sweave("yourfile.Rnw")` in your R console and then running `pdflatex yourfile` in the terminal. There is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922432/more-efficient-r-sweave-texshop-work-flow) discussion in SO about efficient Sweave workflow too.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain directly a PDF typing outside of the R environment (in a Linux console, probably in Windows too) with this command:

```
 R CMD Sweave --pdf file.Rnw
```

Note that if the LaTeX code contain something that must be compiled twice (See [What are the situations where you have to compile a document more than once?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/what-are-the-situations-where-you-have-to-compile-a-document-more-than-once) ) then you must avoid the  `--pdf` option (at least for the final document) and compile the resulting `file.tex` with `pdflatex` as many times as needed.