# line numbers across multicols in scrartcl

Tags: koma-script, two-column, line-numbering

The answer to the [following question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20368/lineno-for-2-column) suggested by @IanThompson with left and right column numbers works sufficiently when we use `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`

However I am using a different document class - that being `{scrartcl}` and cannot get the left column to have line numbers to the left and vice versa for the right coulmn.

Here is some generic code, to work with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[switch, columnwise]{lineno}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Correct formatting line numbers}
\author{Contributions from the world wide web}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \doublespacing

\begin{abstract}
    \begin{linenumbers}
        \lipsum[1-1]
    \end{linenumbers}

\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \begin{linenumbers}

        \section{Introduction}      
        \lipsum[1-3]

        \end{linenumbers}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

As suggested in the linked question at the top of the page, playing around with `columnwise` in `\usepackage[switch, columnwise]{lineno}` does not produce the desired output

Comment: You are referring to a question/answer but i cannot see any. I think what you describe is also going on for the standard classes, so not KOMA specific.

Comment: Do you simply want to write a twocolumn article? If so, just use `twocolumn` globally and kick out `multicol`.

Comment: no I am wanting to mix up one and two column parts, thats why I am using scrartcl

Comment: sorry, the hyperlink did upload.... but now it is

Comment: You want a twocolumn article with a onecolumn abstract, right? For me, this seems to be an XY-problem, so it would be good to know what you want to achieve and not fixing the thought to be solution.

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26999

Comment: Its for a journal paper, the finished document mostly has two columns of text, a combination of tables formatted into (or below) a columns of data, as well as tables spanning across the two columns (ie. \end{multicols}-create table-\begin{multicols}...). Do that explain it enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34092/discussion-between-johannes-b-and-lukeg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this new command on [this German forum](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?76323-lineno-in-Verbindung-mit-multicols-Nummern-au%DFen), which is placed inside of the `multicols` environment. Outside, you can use the regular command for the line numbers.

It requires you to load the `colaction` option for `multicol`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Correct formatting line numbers}
\author{Contributions from the world wide web}

\newcommand\multicollinenumbers{%
 \linenumbers
 \def\makeLineNumber{\docolaction{\makeLineNumberLeft}{}{\makeLineNumberRight}}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing

\begin{abstract}
\begin{linenumbers}
    \lipsum[1-1]
\end{linenumbers}

\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\multicollinenumbers

\section{Introduction}      
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{multicols}
\bigskip
\begin{linenumbers}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the code must work as your image indicates, however my version of texstudio gives me the following error `Unknown option "colaction" for package "multicol".\def`.. Any suggestions how to overcome the problem

Comment: @lukeg Is your Tex Live (and all packages) up to date?

Comment: This is a great help. However, `[pagewise]` does not work, to reset the line number from 1 on each page.