# lineno option switch not working for 2 column along with ltxgrid

Tags: two-column, lineno, ltxgrid

When I tried to use the package `lineno` alongwith `ltxgrid` under two-column layout, it causes line number clash in the text part. I tried using option `switch` ([Lineno for 2 column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20368/lineno-for-2-column)) but still no luck.

Find the MWE in below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{ltxgrid}

\begin{document}
\twocolumngrid
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Current Output:

[image: Current output]

Required Output:

[image: Required output]

Comment: Excuse me for the question, but why are you using `ltxgrid` when `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}` gives your desired output? `ltxgrid` has some compatibility problems, see the [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxgrid).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Main reason is finding convenient with `ltxgrid` package to switch columns. Is there any way to use this package along with `lineno`?

Comment: What do you intend for "switching columns" with `ltxgrid`? From two columns to one column and vice-versa? Unfortunately the solution of the compatibility problem is above my level of knowledge...

Comment: Yes. command `\onecolumn` & `\twocolumn` starts with `\clearpage`, hence finding difficult when both required in the same page. Anyway, thanks for looking into this and updates.

Comment: Have you tried `multicols`?

Comment: Have you looked at packages such as `reledmac` (if I'm remembering the name correctly) for critical editions? Perhaps you'd have better luck with those.

Comment: @cfr: Yes. Package `multicol` is not supporting for Floats. I have not tried `reledmac` yet. Let me check. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Any update here?