# From two columns to one column and vice-versa

Tags: two-column, multicol, ltxgrid

My desired output:

[image: required output]

I tried with packages `multicol` & `ltxgrid` to achieve this output, but, facing the below difficulties:

1. Package `ltxgrid` has some compatibility problems, as per the comments from this link [lineno option switch not working for 2 column along with ltxgrid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377159/lineno-option-switch-not-working-for-2-column-along-with-ltxgrid)
2. Package `multicol` is not supporting Floats inside the `multicols` environment.

Appreciated your response.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Does this help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233904/124842

Comment: \usepackage{float} \begin{figure}[H] will solve the float problem in multicolumn package but I am not sure whether this is a good solution...